# how to debug python in IntelliJ idea using vagrant docker

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, docker, vagrant

I am using Vagrant with a Ubuntu machine. Inside Vagrant I am using multiple docker boxes. One of them is for my Python Django Api. 
Is there any good way to connect to Django with IntelliJ Idea/Pycharm ? 
I am trying to using pycharm-debug.egg but I can't connect. 
Should I forward the port from docker to Vagrant and Vagrant to my machine? 
Any tutorial/help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445718/debug-spring-boot-in-vagrant-and-docker) is for Java but should work for python too